# Representing double values in the exponential format in C#

Tags: c#

Need to display the values in the floating point format as well as in exponential format
 if the value is greater or equal to 0.01 and less than or equal to 1000
 display in the expotential format else display in the floating format

For eg : 3.230000000 is displayed as 3.23
 0.00001 is displayed as 1E-05

But the problem with my code if number given is 1 then the number is displayed as 1.00.

```
  if (dValue >= 0.01|| dValue <= 1000.0)
        return (string.Format("{0:0.##E+00}", dValue));
     else
        return (string.Format("{0:F2}", dValue));
```

Please let me know how to check the number does not contain decimal values

Comment: I wonder about your logic.. >= 0.01 or <= 1000.0 should always be true. Did you mean "and"?

Comment: @raghav55: Please correct your logic as it does not correspond to the written text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Round the number to two decimal places and to an integer, and see if the results are "close enough":

```
if (dValue >= 0.01 && dValue <= 1000.0)
{
    if (Math.Abs(Math.Round(dValue, 2) - Math.Round(dValue, 0)) < 0.005) {
        return string.Format("{0:F0}", dValue);
    else
        return string.Format("{0:F2}", dValue);
}
else return (string.Format("{0:0.##E+00}", dValue));
```

The thing to note here is that (as always with floating point numbers) the comparison between the two rounded results should *not* be an equality comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your last line

```
return (string.Format("{0:F2}", dValue))
```

to

```
return (string.Format("{0:0.##}", dValue))
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider simply using [G format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx).

Or use [Math.Truncate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c2eabd70) to get integral part, that see if it ie the same as original number (need to take into account output format precision to do comparison with desider eps, probably 0.005 in your case).

Answer (score 0):

Too much time. :)

You will get 2 digits maximum with values like 3.234.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Format(0.00001));
        Console.WriteLine(Format(1));
        Console.WriteLine(Format(3.2));
        Console.WriteLine(Format(3.22));
        Console.WriteLine(Format(3.256));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static string Format(double dValue)
    {
        if (dValue >= 0.01 && dValue <= 1000.0)
        {
            int temp = (int)Math.Round(dValue * 100);
            if (temp % 100 == 0)
                return ((int)dValue).ToString();
            else if (temp % 10 == 0)
                return (string.Format("{0:F1}", dValue));
            else
                return (string.Format("{0:F2}", dValue));
        }
        else
            return (string.Format("{0:0.##E+00}", dValue));
    }
}
```

gives

```
1E-05
1
3,2
3,22
3,26
```

Probably there are cleaner solutions?!